# OSX - Create .app file using ant

Tags: macos, ant

I have written an app in Objective-C for running it on Mac(OSX not iOS). I want to use it for direct distribution. In XCode, I can create .app file using Product -> Archive -> Distribute.

How do I create .app file using ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. My ant.xml is as follows

```
<project name="MacAgent" default="MacCompile">
        <property name="keychain.password" value="my_password"/>
        <property name="user" value="my_username"/>
        <property name="project.id" value="my_project_name"/>
        <property name="xcodeHome" value="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"/>

        <target name="MacCompile">
                <exec executable="security">
                        <arg value="unlock-keychain"/>
                        <arg value="-p"/>
                        <arg value="${keychain.password}"/>
                        <arg value="/Users/${user}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"/>
                </exec>
                <exec executable="${xcodeHome}/usr/bin/xcodebuild">
                        <arg value="-project"/>
                        <arg value="${project.id}.xcodeproj"/>
                        <arg value="clean"/>
                        <arg value="build"/>
                </exec>
        </target>
</project>
```